# Scala Tuple not show type mismatch if passing parameter inline

Tags: scala

I have an method that expects (String, Double) as parameter

```
scala> def testTupleType(x: (String, Double)) = {}
testTupleType: (x: (String, Double))Unit

scala> val x: Int = 2
x: Int = 2
```

Then I try to pass the parameter to testTupleType method like that:

```
scala> val testTuple = ("String", x)
testTuple: (String, Int) = (String,2)

scala> testTupleType(testTuple)
<console>:11: error: type mismatch;
 found   : (String, Int)
 required: (String, Double)
              testTupleType(testTuple)
```

It show the error as expected. But when I pass the parameter inline:

```
 scala> testTupleType(("String", x))
```

Do not have any error! I do not know is this because of an implicit conversion here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no implicit conversion from `Int` to `Double` in scala. See **3.5.3
Weak Conformance** in [SLS](http://www.scala-lang.org/docu/files/ScalaReference.pdf).

In case of `testTupleType(testTuple)` error contains all information: `(String, Int)` is not a `(String, Double)`.

With "inline" parameters:

```
testTupleType(("String", x))
```

It means:

```
testTupleType(Tuple2.apply("String", x))
```

Method `apply` accepts 2 type parameters:

```
def apply[T1, T2](_1: T1, _2: T2): (T1, T2)
```

`testTupleType` accepts `(String, Double)`, so the result type of `apply` (`(T1, T2)`) should be `(String, Double)`. After type inference:

```
testTupleType(Tuple2.apply[String, Double]("String", x))
```

or:

```
val a: (String, Double) = Tuple2.apply[String, Double]("String", x)
testTupleType(a)
```

Due to weak conformance you can use `Int` as `Double` here.

Comment: Thanks, I read about the weak conformance but still blur about how it is applied here. Is this the apply method that convert (String, Int) to (String, Double)? How exactly is the conversion?

Comment: @Pham: Method `Tuple2.apply[String, Double]` with specified type parameters accepts `Double` as second parameter and you can pass `Int` to method that accepts `Double`: `def test[T](d: T) = d` => `test[Double]((1: Int))`.

Answer (score 2):

To understand the problem let's look at what `-Xprint:typer` shows:

In the first case you are passing a `testTuple: (String, Int) = (String,2)` into the method which expects: `testTupleType: (x: (String, Double))Unit`, but Scala doesn't have an implicit convertion from `Tuple2[String, Int]` to `Tuple2[String, Double]`:

```
val t = Tuple2[String, Int]("a", 2)
val a: (String, Double) = t
<console>:8: error: type mismatch;
 found   : (String, Int)
 required: (String, Double)
       val a: (String, Double) = t
                                 ^
```

Remember that (String, Int) is just a syntactic sugar for the compiler which calls Tuple2.apply.

So why the seconds snippets works? Because Scala desugars this into the `Tuple2[String, Double]`:

```
private[this] val res1: Unit = testTupleType(scala.Tuple2.apply[String, Double]("String", x.toDouble));
 <stable> <accessor> def res1: Unit = res1
```

To summaries, in the first case you already have a Tuple2[String, Int] and Scala doesn't have an implicit convertion for it to Tuple2[String, Double], but you can make your own:

```
implicit def tsi2tdi(t: Tuple2[String, Int]): Tuple2[String, Double] = (t._1, t._2.toDouble)
```

and in the seconds case it sees the you have a String and an Int and you need to convert them into `Tuple2[String, Double]`.

**Update**

No, it's called not by the `apply` method, it's called by the compiler. While compiling Scala performs different analysis phases, one of which is called `typer`. When `scalac` sees then you have an `Int` in the code, but what you want to get is a `Double` value, it knows that, according to the Weak Conformance rules mentioned by **senia**, it can get a `Double` from `Int` by calling `toDouble` method. That's not an implicit convertion in Scala point of view. If you remember primitive convertions were in C and Java, long before Scala

Comment: so you mean that the apply method actually called toDouble() on the parameter?

Comment: @Pham added some info to the answer

Answer (score 1):

The problem is due to your code depending on implicit conversion in which case it does not happen when you pass the testTuple inline.

If you use `val x:Double = 2` it should work.

Comment: The problem is event I use x: Int, it still works if the parameter is passed "inline"